How to create a free WhatsApp chatbot to manage user access based on predefined phone numbers?
I want to create a WhatsApp chatbot that provides access to certain users based on predefined phone numbers stored in a database. The chatbot should work as follows:

When a user sends a message, the chatbot checks if their phone number exists in a predefined list.
2.If the number exists:
The bot allows further interaction and prompts the user for additional details (e.g., a unique ID).
It retrieves specific information from a database and sends a personalized response to the user.
If the number does not exist:
The bot replies with a message asking the user to contact support via email.
Optionally, it could delete the conversation or log the interaction for future reference.


The solution should be free to set up and operate as much as possible.
It should allow basic automation without requiring advanced paid services or subscriptions.
I’m open to using any platform, tools, or frameworks as long as they meet the above criteria.


This isn't a code writing, review, or recommendation site. You should attempt to create some bare-bones solution to your own prompt and ask specific questions with concise, reproducible code/design examples. See the articles under Asking & Answering here.
